# Python compare two different size of dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a problem about comparing two different size of dafaframes and show the result of match and unmatch.

Two dafaframes is included countries. While one is listed all countries in all over the world (`country_data_df`), another one is consisted of some countries. (`country_list_df`)

Here is the structure of both dataframes

```
Index Country
0     Afghanistan
..     ..
```

Another problem is how to do it via contains method like `Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of) vs  Venezuela`

Here is my code snippet.

```
seen_countries = []
unseen_countries = []
for a in country_list_df:
    if a in country_data_df:
        seen_countries.append(a)
    else:
        unseen_countries.append(a)
```

How can I solve it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Clean your data

The 2nd part of your question deals with comparing dissimilar values in your data. The easiest thing to do would be to standardize your Country names in your list of all countries to values in your data. It's much easier to clean the smaller more finite list of countries to reuse against your larger input data set.

Do the following, once your country list has values that can be compared to your input data.

**clean_data** standardized the values to all lowercase and put them into a **set** which automatically gives you unique values.

**seen_countires** will automatically be created by using **clean_data** when you provide your country column from your input data set.

**unseen_countries** is simply a set of all the countries in the **country_list** - **seen_countries** set.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd


def clearn_data(x):
    retval = set([v.lower() for v in x])
    return retval

if __name__ == "__main__":
    country_data = ["C", "D", "E", "F", "a", "A"]
    country_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e","f","g"]

    country_list_df = pd.DataFrame(country_list, columns=["Country"])
    country_data_df = pd.DataFrame(country_data, columns=["Country"])

    seen_countries = clean_data(country_data_df.Country)
    unseen_countries = clean_data(country_list_df.Country) - seen_countries

    print("__Seen Countries__ ")
    print(seen_countries)

    print("__Unseen Countries__ ")
    print(unseen_countries)
```

## Output

**Seen Countries**
{'c', 'a', 'd', 'f', 'e'}

**Unseen Countries**
{'g', 'b'}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Pandas isin? it is great for comparing dataframes, even if they are different sizes.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': ['a', 'b', 'f'], 'C': ['Z', 'V', 'W']})
other = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 3, 3, 2], 'B': ['e', 'f', 'f', 'e']})
print(df.isin(other))
```

results in:

```
       A      B      C
0   True  False  False
1  False  False  False
2   True   True  False
```